# ASP.NET Web Application calling the Main() method on another project Asynchronously C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a web application that has two main functions: 1. match a user's API key with a database key 2. Let the user input a file and drop it for upload. What I am trying to do now, with a very rudimentary understanding of async, is when the user clicks the "submit" button on the web-page the web-page will then point to the Main() method for execution and then having an output message that it was successful after it is finished. Essentially, what I'm trying to avoid is calling the .exe process directly because this application will be going into a cloud server sometime soon.

I have been thoroughly looking into Tasks and Invoking but it appears that I run into an error that the web-page will load continuously for about 5 minutes and then output a server message saying that it could not "find the server". I know that is mainly due to the fact that my methods aren't structured correctly for asynchronous operation.

my ASP.NET code looks like this (for the button):

```
    private async void Submit1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string fn = Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" + fn;
            if (!File.Exists(SaveLocation))
            {
            File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
            await Task.Run(() => Program.Main());
            //IAsyncResult result = Task.Run(() =>caller.BeginInvoke(null, null));
           //caller.EndInvoke(result);
           Response.Write("The file has been uploaded and the Estimated Values should now be reflected in Rally.");
           }
           else
           {
           File.Delete(SaveLocation);
           File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
           await Task.Run(() => Program.Main());
           //IAsyncResult result = Task.Run(() => caller.BeginInvoke(null, null));
           //caller.EndInvoke(result);
           Response.Write("The file has been uploaded and the Estimated Values should now be reflected in Rally.");
           }
    }
```

As you can see, I have a Task pointing to the Main() method and asking it to Run() asynchronously but I believe I do not understand exactly why it is not functioning. I have also tried it with a delegate and get the same result (as you can tell from the commented code).

I have found answers similar but most of which deal with an async method within the same class. I have researched in advance but have not found something tailored more to what I ask.

What would be the best approach for this (speed-wise)? Any input is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: What does your `Program.Main()` function do?  Are you trying to kick it off in a "fire and forget" fashion, then return to the client while it's still running, to avoid consuming a thread while `Main` waits on I/O, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My main function essentially fires a console application which in turn runs an updater with an API. In addition, my Main() method calls various functions and gives them "Path" values that contain files and executes them with those files accordingly. But to your point - I am, at the moment, trying to "fire and forget" at least for my testing purposes. So, essentially, I would like for my website to call my method and execute it, and once it's done, return back to me telling me it was successfully completed.

Comment: How long does your external console application take to complete?  The symptom in your question sounds like an HTTP timeout -- likely because the clock runs out waiting for your Task to complete.  Also, can you see from server-side logs that the Task has started and that the console app is running?

Comment: My console application generally takes anywhere from 5 - 7 minutes to load all the information from various files and then it does arithmetic operations which in turn post to a website with its built-in API. I believe it is indeed an HTTP timeout, or also the notorious "deadlock" I've heard about. What I'm essentially trying to do is to make an asynchronous call to the Main() method. However, I have often noticed that when I press the "Submit" button it will automatically jump me to the "Successfully Posted" message but no change will take place whatsoever. Also, where would one find the logs?